# embed facebook video with comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I can embed a Facebook video with the following code in my Facebook app:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=XXX" width="720" height="1280" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It just shows the video player. Is it possible to also show the comments and other options of the video, like the screenshot?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Can Embed the Post so users can directly click to see the comments 
[image]

There is no other way to embed the comments that are already made on the Particular Video ON facebook.